# A question about isoclines.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ continuous in $\Omega$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose that an isocline of the differential equation $$y'=f(x,y)$$ satisfies the equation. Then we have to prove that, this isocline have to be a straight line $$\varphi(x) =mx+b.$$ Additional to this we have to prove that if $f$ is derivable then such isocline satisfies the equation $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+f\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0.$$

**My approach:** I think the last part is easy. Since $\varphi(x)=mx+b$ then $\varphi '(x)=m$. So $$\varphi '(x)=f(x,y)=m,\ \forall (x,y)\in\Omega$$ then all the partial derivatives vanishes for  all $(x,y)\in\Omega$. And the result follows. Is that correct?. 
For the first part, can i simply say the following? 
Since an isocline (say y'=m) is solution we have that for all $(x,y)\in \Omega$ $$y'=f(x,y)=m$$ and since $f$ is continuous $$\int y'dx=\int mdx+C\Rightarrow y=mx+C, \ \forall x$$ Is that correct?

Any comment or idea is welcome. Thanks.

**PD:** By isocline i refer to the curves: $$y'=f(x,y)=m$$ where $m$ is a constant.

Comment: Note that I made some changes in Question.